# How to get the 101 triangle in the output?

Tags: java

been through making a few logical code just cant figure out how to get the output of 01 triangle in the desired form the triangle does print out but not according to the require output.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.*;

 public class triangle10{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number ");
        int num =input.nextInt();
         while(num > 0){

                 for(int j=1;j<=num;j++){

                 System.out.print(num);

                }

                System.out.print("\n");

                num--;

         }

    }

     }
    ==================================================================
    if the user gives input as 6

    the out put should be :
      111111    
      00000
      1111
      000
      11
      0
```

Comment: if the input number is 5 , the out should start from 00000 or 11111?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
for(int j=1;j<=num;j++){
     System.out.print(num);
}
```

I think you need to print either a `1` or a `0` (according to your example). So you should compute whether `num` is even or odd, and decide whether to print `0` or `1`.  For example

```
for(int j=1;j<=num;j++){
     System.out.print(1 - num%2);
}
```

Because `num%2 = 0` when num is even, and 1 if it is odd - and it seems you want the opposite. So `1 - num%2` should give you what you need.

Before:

```
Enter a number 
6
666666
55555
4444
333
22
1
```

After:

```
Enter a number 
6
111111
00000
1111
000
11
0
```

Answer (score 1):

You are printing out `num`. Instead you should print out 1 or 0 depending on `num`.

Try this :

```
 while(num > 0){
                 for(int j=1;j<=num;j++){                    
                    int digit = (num + 1) % 2 ;                      
                    System.out.print(digit);
                }
                System.out.print("\n");
                num--;
         }
```

Comment: Except your solution is backwards according to the example given. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change you code like this :

```
boolean flag = false;
         while(num > 0){
                 flag = !flag;
                 for(int j=1;j<=num;j++){
                 if(flag==true)
                 System.out.print("1");
                 else
                     System.out.print("0");

                }

                System.out.print("\n");

                num--;

         }
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make a small change

From

```
  for(int j=1;j<=num;j++){

             System.out.print(num);

            }
```

to

```
  for (int j = 1; j <= num; j++) {

            System.out.print((num-1)%2);

        }
```

And then you will get the expected result:

Take entering 6 for example:

```
Enter a number 
6
111111
00000
1111
000
11
0
```